# how to solve hadoop nodes problem in ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I am installed in Hadoop 3.0.2 in  Ubuntu18 ,but  when  i am starting  dfs.sh , it showing no name node , no data node, after that  when I am typing  the jps, it's shows only 8259 Jps , it didn't show 6 nodes

Comment: You need to look at the log files and see why the processes are failing... And running that command on one node will never show 6 nodes

Answer (score 0):

Go to your hadoop folder and check a directory named **Logs**. Then check for any errors. You may paste them here.

Comment: Edit your post and paste the log files. Then let me know, i will debug for you.